# How to calculate the mean of a column by decade in Python

Tags: python, pandas, rows, mean

[image: Image of dataset]

I am unsure as to how to calculate the mean for a column given specific rows.
I need to calculate the mean of the column Mkt-RF by decade, as in the mean from 193001 to 193912, and so on. I need to do this for each decade until 2016.

Is there also any way to put the results into a new dataframe of its own? With the decade (1920,1930) in one column and the mean of each decade in the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first `3` chars of first column by `str[:3]` with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
df = df['Mkt-RF'].groupby(df['Unnamed:0'].str[:3]).mean()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed:0':['192607','192608','193609','193610','193611'],
                   'Mkt-RF':[4,5,6,7,5]})
print (df)   
   Mkt-RF Unnamed:0
0       4    192607
1       5    192608
2       6    193609
3       7    193610
4       5    193611

#rename column
df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed:0':'YEARMONTH'})

df = df['Mkt-RF'].groupby(df.YEARMONTH.str[:3]).mean().rename('MEAN').reset_index()
df.YEARMONTH = (df.YEARMONTH + '0').astype(int)
print (df)
   YEARMONTH  MEAN
0       1920   4.5
1       1930   6.0
```

Another solution is convert first [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `groupby` by [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) floor divided by `10`:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed:0':'YEARMONTH'})

df.YEARMONTH = pd.to_datetime(df.YEARMONTH, format='%Y%m')
df = df['Mkt-RF'].groupby(df.YEARMONTH.dt.year // 10).mean().rename('MEAN').reset_index()
df.YEARMONTH = df.YEARMONTH *10
print (df)
   YEARMONTH  MEAN
0       1920   4.5
1       1930   6.0
```

Comment: It returns this error for me? "Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas" Not sure what it means.

Comment: It meenas first column is not string. So you can use `df = df['Mkt-RF'].groupby(df['Unnamed:0'].astype(str).str[:3]).mean()` or second solution.

Comment: and small advice - people of `StackOverflow` hate pictures instead text, because text cannot be copied. So you get downvote(s). Also this [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) can help as create nice pandas question.

Comment: Thanks! The second solution works perfectly. Is there any way to add a  column with the standard deviations of each decade as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use `df = df['Mkt-RF'].groupby(df.YEARMONTH.dt.year // 10).agg(['mean', 'std']).add_prefix('_').reset_index()`